# Quick Sort Swapping Elements With already Sorted List

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Whenever the list is sorted from the beginning `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` the quick sort algorithm still swaps elements, and all the tutorials out there have similar code to what I have.  Now, they don't ever mention why it does it or how I would solve the problem.

`lessThanOrEqualTo` is `<=` and `swapElements` swaps element `A` with `B`. I am using the functions to count how many times I swap or compare elements. As I stated before, this works decent enough, but the problem is that it should say `0` swaps for a sorted list, but it doesn't. If anyone could help me, I would appreciate it very much.

**Code:**

```
static int partition(ElementType* arrayToSort, int low, int high,   Statistics* statistics)
{
    int pivot = arrayToSort[high];
    int pIndex =(low-1);
    for (int j=low; j<=high-1; j++)
    {
        if(lessThanOrEqualTo(arrayToSort[j], pivot, statistics))
        {
            pIndex++;
            swapElements(&arrayToSort[pIndex], &arrayToSort[j], statistics);
        }
    }
    swapElements(&arrayToSort[pIndex+1], &arrayToSort[high], statistics);
    return (pIndex+1);
}

static int partition_r(ElementType* arrayToSort, int low, int high, Statistics* statistics)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int random = low + rand() % (high-low);
    swapElements(&arrayToSort[random], &arrayToSort[high], statistics);
    return partition(arrayToSort, low, high, statistics);
}

static void quickMain(ElementType* arrayToSort, int low, int high, Statistics* statistics)
{
    if (low<high)
    {
        int pIndex = partition_r(arrayToSort, low, high, statistics);
        quickMain(arrayToSort, low, pIndex-1, statistics);
        quickMain(arrayToSort, pIndex+1, high, statistics);
    }

}

static void quickSort(ElementType* arrayToSort, size_t size, Statistics* statistics)
{
    int n = size-1;
    quickMain(arrayToSort, 0, n, statistics);
}
```

**Result:**

```
---------------------------------------------
--------         Quick sort         ---------
---------------------------------------------

Unsorted: 
  10 element:    19 comparisons,    22 swaps
  20 element:    85 comparisons,    76 swaps
  40 element:   244 comparisons,   184 swaps

Sorted: 
  10 element:    19 comparisons,    21 swaps
  20 element:    62 comparisons,    45 swaps
  40 element:   194 comparisons,   102 swaps

Reverse sorted: 
  10 element:    19 comparisons,    20 swaps
  20 element:    74 comparisons,    70 swaps
  40 element:   180 comparisons,   160 swaps
```

Comment: Quicksort has poor behaviour, in general, on sorted data.  You can't use a naïve Quicksort and expect good behaviour.  Using a random partition improves the performance, but means you never get zero swaps.  If you think your data will usually be almost sorted, maybe Quicksort isn't the best choice.  It is, however, an excellent choice when the data will not be sorted.  You could always take a precautionary step of randomizing the data before sorting it – though that might cost enough to outweigh the benefit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler would you say that using random partition in this case is bad and I should not use it, but then when I dont use it the comparison and swaps get ridiculous

Comment: No; using a random partition is one of the better ways to almost guarantee O(N.logN) performance from Quicksort. Your goal of no swaps on already sorted data is not sensible — IMO it's not achievable using Quicksort without a preliminary pass to see whether the data is already in sorted order — and that preliminary pass is a time-waster when your data is normally not sorted. You'll have to make a judgement call on whether your data is normally sorted on input. If it is, then maybe the preliminary pass is a benefit. You can use the full Quicksort as soon as any elements are out of sequence.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yeah you are right, and even tho I am swapping when it is sorted that is the worst case for quick sort, and without it I would have worse performance overall ty again for the long answers really appreciate it